# Convertir .py a exe py installer

Tags: python-3.7, pycharm

Cordiales saludos a todos,

Quiero convertir un archivo de Python `.py` a un executable `.exe` con pycharm

Estoy tratando de usar Py Installer pero me arroja error en los comandos tengo la version de python `Python 3.7.3`

En el entrono de variables tengo las rutas direecionadas hacia donde esta instalado python:

```
C:\Users\dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
C:\Users\dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
```

Este es el error que me arroja al tratar de convertir el archivo a exe.

> C:\Users\dani\PycharmProjects\Scraping>pyinstaller --onefile MiArchivo.py
>   'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error? ya he leido varias posibles soluciones y mencionan que el problema está en el entorno de variables, pero ya mostré donde estan instalado python y no he podido solucionar el problema.

Edito Agrego imagenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen nueva:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero me puedan ayudar. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pyinstaller` lo instalaste con `pip`? Desde *PyCharm*?
`PyCharm` crea un entorno de python por defecto al abrir un nuevo proyecto, si instalaste `pyinstaller` desde *PyCharm*, muy probablemente lo hayas instalado para ese entorno y no para tu entorno global de python.

Cerciórate que `pyinstaller` esté instalado en el entorno global de python para poder ejecutar el comando que mencionas, y además, que las rutas de python estén sí dentro de las variables de entorno pero sobre todo dentro de la variable **`PATH`**

También otro problema puede ser que tengas dos versiones de python instaladas, por ejemplo python2 y python3, es común que `pip` haga referencia al de python2 (o al primero que instalaste), mientras que, si mal no recuerdo `pip3` hace referencia al de python3.

#### Edit 1:

Muy probablemente sea por lo último (varias versiones de python y cada una en diferentes rutas) por lo que veo en la imagen donde se ejecuta `pip install pyinstaller`. Intenta agregar `C:\Users\jdani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts` a **`PATH`**.

Comment: He agredo a la pregunta principal imágenes con el Path donde tengo Python y tanto como en Pycharm y Python (cmd) me arrroja el mismo error.
Algo adicional que pueda hacer?

Comment: En las imágenes que agregaste, estás ejecutando pyinstaller y pip desde el intérprete de python, pero los debes ejecutar como comandos desde el command prompt

Comment: Gúzman
Agregue una nueva imagen, el comando pip install pyinstaller <- me ha instalado pyinstaller.
Pero el comando pyinstaller -h no me funciona, arroja el error mostrado en la imagen.
Comando no reconocido.
La sintaxis es diferente o que mas puedo tener incorrecto?

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, si eso no funciona puedes mostrar la salida del siguiente comando `where pip` y después ejecutar `dir` con el resultado del comando anterior, por favor.

Comment: Muchas gracias Benjamín si me funciono agregando la ruta:
C:\Users\jdani\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts al path y he podido crear finalmente mi archivo ejecutable.
Muchas gracias por todo tu apoyo y que tengas felices fiestas!!!!